# How to properly display sufficient tick markers using plt.savefig?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

After running the code below, the axis tick markers all overlap with each other. At this time, each marker could still have good resolution when zooming popped up by `plt.show()`. However, the figure saved by `plt.savefig('fig.png')` would lost its resolution. Can this also be optimised?

[image]

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a=np.random.random((1000,1000))

# create scaled formatters / for Y with Atom prefix
formatterY = FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: 'Atom {0:g}'.format(y))
formatterX = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(x))

# apply formatters 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatterY)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatterX)

plt.imshow(a, cmap='Reds', interpolation='nearest')

# create labels
plt.xlabel('nanometer')
plt.ylabel('measure')
plt.xticks(list(range(0, 1001,10)))
plt.yticks(list(range(0, 1001,10)))

plt.savefig('fig.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it help to set a fig size?

Comment: Are you asking how to save the zoomed image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve it by setting the size of the figure, e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15., 15.)
```

As pointed out by @PatrickArtner in the comments, you can then also avoid the overlap of x-ticks by

```
plt.xticks(list(range(0, 1001, 10)), rotation=90)
```

instead of

```
plt.xticks(list(range(0, 1001,10)))
```

The rest of the code is completely unchanged; the output then looks reasonable (but is too large to upload here).

Comment: to alleviate the overwriting on x axis - labels  a `plt.xticks(list(range(0, 1001,10)), rotation=90)`  would help a lot. - not answering for that little bit :) maybe add it to yours?