# Python: plotting an exponential on an axis

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, ode, exp

I'm currently working on a piece of code to model the evolution of the dark energy equation of state parameter `w` with the scale factor `a`. In order to do this I am solving a system of three coupled ODEs, however the derivative used is with respect to e-foldings `N = ln(a)` (in the code `x = w` and `ln(a) = t` for simplicity). I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

def f(s,t):
p = 1.0
G = 1.0 + (1.0/p) 
xm = 0
x = s[0]
y = s[1]
z = s[2]
dxdt = (x - 1.0)*(3.0*(1.0 + x) - z*math.sqrt(3.0*(1.0 + x)*y))
dydt = -3.0*(x - xm)*y*(1.0 - y)
dzdt = -math.sqrt(3.0*(1.0 + x)*y)*(G - 1.0)*(z**2)
return [dxdt, dydt, dzdt]

t = np.linspace(0.0001,1,10000)
s0 = [-0.667,0.01,0.45]

s = odeint(f,s0,t)

plt.plot(t,s[:,0],'b-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('e-foldings, N = ln(a)')
plt.ylabel('Equation of state parameter w')
plt.show()
```

which gives me [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUGV5.png).

This works fine, however I want the x-axis in units of `a` and not `N = ln(a)` but I can't figure out how to make it work. I've tried changing the plot line to `plt.plot(math.exp(t),s[:,0],'b-')` but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bradleyaldous/propr2.py", line 26, in <module>
plt.plot(math.exp(t),s[:,0],'b-')
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
[Finished in 6.0s]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've tried using `np.exp()` in the plot line like I did with the

Comment: Not an answer but you may find [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/scales/scales.html) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171618/changing-plot-scale-by-a-factor-in-matplotlib) helpful.

Comment: @mikey thanks for the reply, I thought about using these axes but I need the exp(my current x) as my x-axis - I don't know if I can apply these to here but I'll have a play around

Comment: Just use NumPy for operations like `exp`, `sqrt`, ... (i.e. `np.exp(t)`) NumPy can directly do this on the entire matrix.

Comment: P.S. You should try to limit your question to the exact problem, and omit the large context in which you apply it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This is not only good practice for this platform, but will also help you to identify problems, and find solutions for them much quicker.

Comment: You can also keep your xtick locations and change the displayed value. Maybe plt.xticks (matplotlib docs) would be easier ..