# Change units of plot axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, apache-axis

I want the scatterplot to get the units in millions (e.g. 10e6) instead of to the default unit for this data set (i.e. 10e9). Ideally, both axis would look identical with same axis units and same ticks.
I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171618/changing-plot-scale-by-a-factor-in-matplotlib) to no avail. Am I missing something?

Example code:

```
mtcars = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv')
display(mtcars.head())
mtcars['qsec'] = mtcars['qsec']*100000000
mtcars['wt'] = mtcars['wt'] *100000000
display(mtcars.head())

plt.scatter(x=mtcars['qsec'],y=mtcars['wt'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with scale 10e9 and different ticks]

Comment: i usually use this `OOMFormatter`: [Set scientific notation with fixed exponent and significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42658124/13138364)

Comment: in your case, something like `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(OOMFormatter(6, '%1.1f'))`

Comment: `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(6, 6))`?

Comment: that also works, but i think you just lose control of the decimal formatting

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will use @Emma solution as it is neater.