# Matplotlib, y-axis values are wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to inspect 2012 USA Elections for most voted 2 nominees and display their votes by states on a bar graph. I have the disctricts and votes for each nominee in 3 different lists. For example Obama's votes are stored in a list :

votesOne = [795696, 122640, 1025232, 394409, 7854285, 1323102, 905083, 242584, 267070, 4237756, 1773827, 306658, 212787, 3019512, 1152887, 822544, 440726, 679370, 809141, 401306, 1677844, 1921290, 2564569, 1546167, 562949, 1223796, 201839, 302081, 531373, 369561, 2125101, 415335, 4485741, 2178391, 124827, 2827709, 443547, 970488, 2990274, 279677, 865941, 145039, 960709, 3308124, 251813, 199239, 1971820, 1755396, 238269, 1620985, 69286]

Here's the part of my code:

```
    x = np.arange(len(states))
    y1 = votesOne
    y2 = votesTwo
    width = 0.2
    plt.bar(x+0.2, y1, width, color='cyan')
    plt.bar(x, y2, width,  color='orange')
    plt.xticks(x, states)
    plt.xlabel("States")
    plt.ylabel("Votes")
    plt.legend([mostVoted[0], secondVoted[0]])
```

But my graph shows up like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/csxcR.png)
The scaling is right, but the numbers on the y-axis are way smaller than the actual votes. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the y-axis values are represented in million units (`1e6` at the top of the y-axis). If you want to change the scale, I suggest you [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171618/changing-plot-scale-by-a-factor-in-matplotlib).